# PowerShell Greater than not working

Tags: powershell

I am having a consistent issue with getting a script to search for a word and a number and if that number is greater than the one defined it sends me an alert. I can't seem to find any answers and I have to believe this has been done before. The script is only sending me an email when I have the value it looks for set to 0. Why would only 0 work? At one point I was using `Queued:\s+(\d+)')` but I had to change that because it was coming back at null and not working. The below script is working but it only works when the value is set to 0 -

```
$Output = 'D:\test.data\QueuedJobs.txt'
d:
set-location -Path 'D:\program files\veritas\netbackup\bin\admincmd'
.\bpdbjobs -summary -L > $Output

[int]$Queued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value

if ($Queued -ge 10){"Queued is {0}" -f $Queued}
```

The issue I've been having is the output it's trying to read has a lot of spaces. This is what the file it produces looks like -

```
Queued:                                130
Waiting-to-Retry:                        0
Active:                         124
Successful:                   26913
Partially Successful:           114
Failed:                         186
Incomplete:                       0
Suspended:                        0
Total:                        27337
```

Comment: The code runs here without a problem, except that your if misses the part  in curly braces.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Changed your question with code here working (with simulated file $output)

Comment: That doesn't seem to want to play nice https://imgur.com/XBWTGeu

Comment: sorry missed the opening curly brace - and don't mix with the other code. There is only one set of {} per if

Comment: So if I want to have it say over 100 the -ge should be 100 and {100}? Because if I do that it's sending me an email regardless of what number I put in. If queued is 4 and I say email me over 100 it's still sending an email

Comment: Read the help `Get-Help about_if`

Comment: I see that...It just doesn't seem to want to filter out a number. It's emailing me regardless

Comment: This is the 7th time in 2 days you've asked essentially the same question. Please stop.

Comment: What does .Matches.Value deliver?  If it always returns one,  then it"s clear why you only get results when you test for zero.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a bit of a different pattern.

```
[int]$Queued = (Select-String -Path .\mat.txt -Pattern 'Queued:\s+(\d+)').Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

**EDIT:**

Your expression, with a positive lookbehind, can be used.

```
[int]$Queued = (Select-String -Path $Output -Pattern '(?<=Queued:\s+)\d+').Matches.Value
```

Comment: at .\mat.txt should I use my path of D:\test.data\queuedjobs.txt ?

Comment: Yes, use your file in the path. I created `mat.txt` for testing locally. Replace `.\mat.txt` with `$Output`.